# Getting the month to show date name rather than number when pulling each month in the year

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, date

I am pulling data that lists each month of the year but the month column states the first day of each year, how can I make this show the full month name?
Here is some of what I have. I read similar questions and tried to add in what it stated everywhere but I couldn't get it work, help?

```
SELECT a.MonthDate
,Sum(a.ScrapPcs) / (Sum(a.GrossPcs)*1.00) As ScrapPct
,0.05 As ScrapTarget
 ,sum (a.GrossPcs) As 'Total Parts Cast'
 ,sum (a.ScrapPcs) as 'Total Parts Scrap'

,CASE 

 WHEN Sum(a.ScrapPcs) / (Sum(a.GrossPcs)*1.00) <= 0.05 THEN 1

 WHEN Sum(a.ScrapPcs) / (Sum(a.GrossPcs)*1.00) >= 0.9*.05 THEN -1

 ELSE 0

 END 
 AS Status


FROM 
(

SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, b.CreationProdDate), 0) As MonthDate
      ,Count(b.BOOKING_ID) As ScrapPcs
      , 0 As GrossPcs

FROM dbo.CPC_BOOKING b

WHERE b.CreationProdDate Between DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GetDate()), 0) AND DateAdd("d", -1, GetDate())
and CPC_BookingTyp_ID in (2,8)
and ManufacturingPlant in (90002604,90017699, 90017705)


GROUP BY DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, b.CreationProdDate), 0)


UNION ALL 


SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, n.ProductionDate), 0) As MonthDate
      ,0 As ScrapPcs
      ,Sum(n.Quantity) As GrossPcs

 FROM [NORIS].[dbo].[MDL_Data_Ultimate] n

WHERE n.ProductionDate Between DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GetDate()), 0) AND DateAdd("d", -1, GetDate())
and n.ManufacturingPlantGroup = 1

GROUP BY DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, n.ProductionDate), 0)
) a


group by a.MonthDate
```

Thanks in advance, anything helps

Comment: `MySQL` or `SQL Server` ?

Comment: This can't be both mysql and sqlserver and since the answer is different for each we are unable to answer.

Comment: Use Date_Format().
Read this for more information https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp

Comment: This should be one of MySQL OR SQL server, hence these two has different approach

Comment: @bksi -- actually not so hard to write a solution that works in both... maybe that is what he needs.  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySQL:
https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-monthname-function.php
Use the MONTHNAME function as per the example on that webpage.

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(a.MonthDate)
```

Comment: Thanks, I read similar things but didn't figure out exactly where to put it till your answer

Comment: No problem, feel free to accept my answer as the most correct :-)

Comment: @JohnMitchell -- or at least as the person who won the 50% lottery on which platform he was using.

Answer (score 1):

For MS SQL Server:

If you want the month name use this in the derived table:

```
SELECT datename(month,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, b.CreationProdDate), 0)) As MonthDate
```

That is, you want to apply the `datename(month, date)`function to the first column of both unioned queries.

Comment: I think you want `datename(month,b.CreationProdDate)` won't that be the same?

Comment: @Hogan I don't think so, the datename dunction expects both datepart and date as arguments according to https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I have two arguements -- but I edited it, are you seeing the first version?

Comment: @Hogan Ah, yeah, I saw the first version

Comment: my point is the first column is some fancy code to get the first day of the month, you don't need that with the datename function

Comment: @Hogan i get what you are saying, I just inserted the datename function around the op's code. And btw, it will work as is, see http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8b059/1 for an example :) but anyhow, `datename(month,b.CreationProdDate)` should be enough

Comment: I know it will work -- I edited that out too.   like I said... can't get it right the first time.